# Pull request creation failed. Validation failed: was submitted too quickly

Tags: github, pull-request

[image: ScreenShot of my problem]

I'm trying to create a pull request, but this error keeps showing up.

I'm constantly trying to make this PR, but it's not working. I don't know where the problem is, I'm also trying by writing commands in git to make this PR and push it into my origin repository.

Comment: Looks like you're hitting some kind of internal rate limiting on creating Github resources. It is discussed [here](https://github.com/cli/cli/issues/4801) and [here](https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/55772). Looks like the only way to mitigate this is to wait for up to an hour.

Answer (score 1):

GitHub is facing an unprecedented amount of spam and abuse on its platform. People try sneaking in security bugs in automated pull-requests, deploy bitcoin miners on GitHub actions, take over people's GitHub CodeSpaces, gain access to credentials to publish to package management sites, like npm and nuget and so much more.

To combat this abuse, GitHub has a number of documented and undocumented rate limits in place. Mostly these are there to prevent automation from automatically spamming 100s of repos at once.

A number of factors are weighed in, like the number of requests made by a specific user. But also the IP address. But also a number of undocumented elements, and I'm speculating here, things like your current location, account age and your general "standing".

If you are hit by a rate limit, [you can request the status of your public rate limits through the API fo REST calls](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/rate-limit?apiVersion=2022-11-28) and [a similar API for GraphQL](https://docs.github.com/en/graphql/overview/resource-limitations#rate-limit). That should tell you the current number of remaining calls and when there values will reset.

If you're hit by an undocumented (or so-called 2nd level rate limit), then there is no way to easily check the reason. This is to prevent bad actors from knowing exactly what's getting them temporarily banned.

In most cases rate limits reset completely after an hour.

If you need higher rate limits, [there are higher numbers available to  GitHub Enterprise clients](https://docs.github.com/en/apps/creating-github-apps/registering-a-github-app/rate-limits-for-github-apps#determining-rate-limits-for-a-github-app).